# How to test nested asynchronous calls in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, chai

I would like to unit-test the function getAuthorizedUsers from the following module. The core functionality that I need to test is in the callback function of DB.getUsers. I could not find a way to mimic the callback of DB.getUsers.

```
(function () {
    const DB = require('./DB');

    function getAuthorizedUsers(req, res, callback) {
        DB.getUsers(req.db, req.userId, function(err, users) {
            users.push({id: 0});
            req.users = users;
            callback(req, res);
        });
    }

    module.exports = {
        getAuthorizedUsers: getAuthorizedUsers
    };
})();
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var chai = require("chai");
    var User = require("./User");

    suite("API", function () {
        suite("getAuthorizedUsers", function() {
            var req = {
                db: {},
                userId: '',
            };
            var res = {};
            test("adds admin to list of authorized users", function() {
                User.getAuthorizedUsers(req, res, function(req, res) {
                    //assert that req contains the correct list of authorized users
                });
            });
        });
    });
}());
```

I have changed names, and logic of code for simplification. So, forgive me if code does not follow the best practices or does not make sense.

EDIT: Do you have any suggestions on how to stub the "DB.getUsers"?

Comment: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you do testing for node.js

1. Use jasmine or mocha frameworks - they support clean syntax for testing async stuff. http://tobyho.com/2015/12/16/mocha-with-promises/
2. Stick to use promises instead of callbacks for most situations. It will make your life a lot easier, with some tradeoff's on edge-cases.
3. You don't need to use IIFE in node.js since each module has it's own globals.
4. These will help you to mock node modules:

   - https://github.com/mockery/mockery
   - https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right, it is Nodejs. My problem still in "DB.getUsers". What I am trying to acheive is to stub it so I would change its implementation and therefore fire its callback with whatever users list I want. Maybe the question is not phrased right.

Comment: Ah, understood. Updated the answer with stuff for mocking modules.

Comment: proxyquire seems what I am looking for. I will check it and then mark your answer as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Just be aware that it works only for one level deep. For example if you'll want to mock a module B in chain "test -> A -> B" it will not work IIRC.